# Time out error on heroku using puma server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, github, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

I deployed my rails project on heroku but I am facing timeout error on heroku. I am using puma server on heroku. My project is about scraping web data using URL. I also tried webrick & unicorn server. Can anybody suggest me the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking information about what is causing the Timeout error. As you are fetching data from other web pages, it's likely the timeout is caused by a not responding HTTP URL.

In this case, the web server you are using may be irrelevant. In fact, Heroku imposes a [request timeout](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout) of 30 seconds. If your app doesn't return a response within 30 seconds, the request is terminated by Heroku. It doesn't really matter which web server you are using.

In order to solve this problem you have to

1. set a timeout in your code (you can use the `Timeout` library) to make sure that no external HTTP request takes more than a certain period of time, which must be lower than the Heroku timeout.
2. you may also want to move lon-running tasks away from the context of a request into async jobs that are not subject to the request timeout in Heroku. However, in order to do that you will require a background job system such as Sidekiq or Resque.

Comment: Actually i am fetching data from other site using URL.I used sidekiq but it didn't work........i want to run task in background...but i dont know how to do it